# Laravel kreait/laravel-firebase install failed

Tags: laravel, firebase-realtime-database, laravel-package

I am working on a project and  tried to install firebase package using:

```
composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
```

But it returns different errors:

```
Using version ^4.1 for kreait/laravel-firebase
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update kreait/laravel-firebase
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - lcobucci/jwt[4.1.5, ..., 4.2.x-dev] require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - kreait/laravel-firebase 4.1.0 requires kreait/firebase-php ^6.0 -> satisfiable by kreait/firebase-php[6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev].
    - kreait/firebase-php[6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.1.0, ..., 4.2.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires kreait/laravel-firebase ^4.1 -> satisfiable by kreait/laravel-firebase[4.1.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - D:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require kreait/laravel-firebase:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require kreait/laravel-firebase:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

How can i fix this problem?. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try the solutions offered by that error message itself? "_require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension._"

Comment: use `sudo apt install php-sodium` for linux for xampp, uncomment extension=php_sodium.dll in php.ini

Answer (score 4):

Here's the steps you've provided solution.

**Step 1: Activate Sodium Extension**

1. Navigate to the PHP directory in XAMPP (`D:\xampp\php\`) and locate the `php.ini` file.
2. Search for 'sodium' in the `php.ini` file.
3. You'll find a line `;extension=sodium`. Remove the semicolon `;` at the beginning of the line to uncomment it.
4. Save the changes made to the `php.ini` file.
5. Reload Apache to apply the changes.
6. Run Composer again.

**Step 2: Install Laravel Firebase Package**

1. If it exists, delete the `composer.lock` file.
2. Run the following Composer command in your project directory:

   ```
   composer require kreait/laravel-firebase --with-all-dependencies
   ```

These steps should help in activating the Sodium extension and installing the `kreait/laravel-firebase` package along with its dependencies using Composer within your XAMPP environment.

Comment: Would recommend formatting the answer, like the other answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install/activate sodium goto, `D:\xampp\php\` and open file `php.ini`.

Now search for `sodium`

You will see `;extension=sodium`

Remove semi colon `;` and save file.

Now reload apache, and run the composer again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Murad Ali worked for me. The only change was I accessed the php.ini file via Xamp the windows app. To edit go to config then select php.ini from the list and edit from there. Scroll to Line 953

[the php.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rltII.png)
[xamp server screen and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4uLm.png)